# Using TMR0 to time an event

Tags: pic, timer, microchip

i'm trying to use TMR0 on a PIC18F2420 to time the opening of a device and display the percentage it is opened. the issue i'm having is that it has frozen up pretty much all other operations. i'm not quite sure where i went wrong. if anyone could help i'd greatly appreciate it. i have my internal clock set for 4MHz and Tmr2 is keeping track on an external interrupt.

my main code upon setup sets
    GIE = 1;
    GIEL =1;

and my routine that i'm tracking sets
TMR0ON = 1;

```
void int (void)

{
RCONbits.IPEN=1;    
INTCON2bits.RBPU=0;
INTCONbits.INT0IE=1;
INTCON3bits.INT1IE=1;

INTCON3bits.INT1IP=1;

INTCON2bits.INTEDG0=0; //interrupt at falling edge
INTCON2bits.INTEDG1=0;
GIE=1;   // Global interrupt enable
INTCON2bits.TMR0IP=0;
INTCON2bits.RBIP=0;
INTCONbits.TMR0IE =1;
INTCON2bits.TMR0IP = 0;
}

//========================================================================
void Counter(void)
{

Timer0count=0;
TMR0ON=0;
TMR0=0x00;
//PR2=0xFF;
T0CON=0xD0;
TMR0IF=0;
TMR0IE=1;
TMR0IP=0;
TMR0ON=0;

}
//========================================================================
void Counter1(void)
{

//  Timer0count=0;
TMR0ON=0;
TMR0=0x00;
//  PR2=0xFF;
T0CON=0xD0;
TMR0IF=0;
TMR0IE=1;
TMR0IP=0;
TMR0ON=1;

}
//========================================================================
#pragma interrupt_level 0
void interrupt low_priority lowISR()
{
if(TMR0IE && TMR0IF)
{
    if((Timer0count) >= 16)  //915 is a count for a minute
    {

        TMR0IF=0;
        TMR0IE=0;   
        TMR0=0x00;  
        Timer0count=0;
        TMR0ON=0;
        percent++;
    }
    else
    {       
        TMR0IF=0;
        TMR0IE=1;   
        TMR0=0x00;  
        Timer0count++;          
    }
Counter1();
}
}
```

Comment: How often your timer interrupt is called? If it is too often, it is just consuming the whole processing power. Reduce the interrupt resolution.

Comment: it should be called every time tmr0 overflows

Comment: Thanks, cap :) Numbers please. I don't have time to dive into datasheets.

Comment: How exactly do you know it has 'frozen all other operations'? Could it also be the counter is just not counting for some reason?

Comment: @CamilStaps the display wont change unless in go into the menu and when it exits the menu it reads the new value

Comment: Alright, but that doesn't tell me anything because I don't know your program and what it's supposed to do. For example: is it possible the chip gets stuck in an infinite loop? Is it possible that the ISR takes up so much time the processor doesn't have time for anything else? Or is it just that the loading bar is 'frozen', which could also be caused by a faulty counter? Since you mention you can go into the menu, the first two aren't so likely, but it depends on your setup.

Comment: @CamilStaps i'm sorry. i think it's the ISR is taking up too much time. the ISR for my Menu is a High priority and the ISR for the timer is low Priority

Comment: Thank you for the info. The existing answers are good in that case :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to follow what you think your code is supposed to do since it's pretty much devoid of comments.  Besides, your code isn't working, so it's irrelevant anyway.  Let's step back and think about how to best attack this problem.

You apparently want to track how much accumulated time some digital signal spends in either state.  If this is happening in human time, as implied by "opening" and "closing" of some device, then checking periodically is fine.  Every 10 ms should be fine, probably even every 100 ms.  Note that the actual sampling period doesn't matter as long as its regular and fast enough since you ultimately only care about the ratio of open to closed time.  The samples per unit time cancel out.

Timer 2 with its built-in period register is good for setting up a periodic interrupt.  In this interrupt, all you do is increment one of two counters depending on whether the device is open or closed.  These probably need to be wide counters, like 32 bits each.

When you are asked for the fraction of lid open time, the foreground code grabs a snapshot of the two counters and does the divide.

When you grab the snapshots, you have to make sure you are getting a consistent value since a interrupt could come along and change things between reading the individual bytes of the value.  There are two usual ways to get around this: disable interrupts for the few cycles it takes to copy each value, or after reading the value, check it again, and retry if it changed.

Comment: "Besides, your code isn't working, so it's irrelevant anyway."? I'm happy he shared his code, otherwise people would've asked for it for sure. For the rest, +1.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have too much "stuff" happening inside your interrupt handler.

There is certainly some duplication, for example you have "TMR0IF=0;" both in your if/else as well as in your "Counter1" function which you call immediately after the if/else.

Depending on your compiler's optimisation abilities you might also consider not making function calls from inside your interrupt handler in order to save on a couple of instructions for the function call/return and maybe some stack management.

You can also increase the prescaler setting you've assigned to TMR0 so that it overflows and interrupts less often (but obviously account for that in your measurement calculations).